# Object files are getting compiled every time when changing from one directory to the other and invoke make from there

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

Below are the details of my test project

```
myproject/
|
|- Makefile1
|- test_module.c
|- test/
     |- Makefile2
```

Below are the contents of my make files

```
Makefile 1:

obj-m:=test_module.o
all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules;
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean;

Makefile2:
obj-m:=../test_module.o
all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules;
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean;
```

When i invoke make in the `myproject` directory, test_module.o is getting compiled. If i cd to the `test/` directory and invoke make, again  test_module.o is getting compiled. That is not my expected behavior. Make should not compile `test_module.o` again since it is already compiled. It should use that object file to generate corresponding executable or kernel module. Do i miss any thing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the Linux kernel build system object files are not reused for *different* targets(e.g., kernel modules).

This is caused by auxiliary build files, stored alongside with objects files. E.g., in you case `.test_module.o.cmd` uses exact path to `test_module.o`. When file is created by Makefile1, this path ends with `test_module.o`, but when Makefile2 is in question, path ends with `test/../test_module.o`.